# Enable executing multiple statements while execution via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a DDL object (`create_function_foo`) that contains a create function statement. In first line of it I put `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS foo;` but `engine.execute(create_function_foo)` returns:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Use multi=True when executing multiple statements
```

I put `multi=True` as parameter for `create_engine`, `engine.execute_options` and `engine.execute` but it doesn't work.

**NOTE**: `engine` if my instance of `create_engine`

**NOTE**: I'm using python 3.2 + mysql.connector 1.0.12 +  sqlalchemy 0.8.2

```
create_function_foo = DDL("""\
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS foo;
CREATE FUNCTION `foo`(
    SID INT
) RETURNS double
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  ...
END
""")
```

Where I should put it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`multi=True` is a requirement for MySql connector. You can not set this flag passing it to SQLAlchemy methods. Do this:

```
conn  = session.connection().connection
cursor = conn.cursor()  # get mysql db-api cursor
cursor.execute(sql, multi=True)
```

More info here: http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg30129.html

Comment: TypeError: execute() takes no keyword arguments

Answer (score 6):

Yeah... This seems like a bummer to me. I don't want to use the ORM so the accepted answer didn't work for me.

I did this instead:

```
with open('sql_statements_file.sql') as sql_file:
    for statement in sql_file.read().split(';'):
        if len(statement.strip()) > 0:
             connection.execute(statement + ';')
```

And then this failed for a CREATE function.... YMMV.

Comment: A more reliable way of splitting the script into statements is to use a SQL parsing library e.g. `sqlparse.split(sqlparse.format(self.sql, strip_comments=True))`

Comment: Although this is a good idea for simple scripts that you can guarantee don't have oddly placed semicolons, there are some common edge cases that make this a bad idea in practice. Note that semicolons in comments or strings (IE `--;` or `';'`) will cause confusion to this setup. I would also recommend using a sql parsing lib.

Comment: @JakobLovern for sure. The idea here was never meant to be more than a solution to a problem. I was using it for DDL; a clean script; if any comments, none with semi-colons. I just needed each query to run, individually. That is all.

Answer (score 4):

There are some cases where SQLAlchemy does not provide a generic way at accessing some `DBAPI` functions, such as as dealing with multiple result sets. In these cases, you should deal with the raw DBAPI connection directly.

[From SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#multiple-result-sets):

```
connection = engine.raw_connection()
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from table1; select * from table2")
    results_one = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.nextset()
    results_two = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

[You can also do the same using mysql connector as seen here:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

```
operation = 'SELECT 1; INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (); SELECT 2'
for result in cursor.execute(operation, multi=True):
  if result.with_rows:
    print("Rows produced by statement '{}':".format(
      result.statement))
    print(result.fetchall())
  else:
    print("Number of rows affected by statement '{}': {}".format(
      result.statement, result.rowcount))
```

Comment: sqlalchemy solution doesn't seem to work. One query works, two queries throw ProgrammingError. Has there been a change in sqlalchemy API?