# How to fix multiple error inserting in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I use the following query:

```
cur.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
```

Where `data` is:

```
[('ON-LOOK', 'ONLOOK KOREA', 'master@on-look.co.kr', 'Entertainment', '1.287', 'USK: All ages', 'https://www.google.com/url', 'https://ama.com', 'December 13, 2016', '//lh3.googleusercontent.com/bZrL9zRTXujVSFsNS_vD8AomApZeP2xgI1vGTsOz_zvoVKOz5T9pk7nFB3ONXXf04rqj=w300', '100 - 500', '4.7', '6', '4.3 and up')]
```

And `sql` is:

```
sql = """insert into apps_global (app_name, app_developer, app_email, app_category, app_version, app_age, app_website, app_url, app_developer_url, app_updated, app_image, app_installations, app_score, app_score_count, app_android \
      ) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"""
```

When I try to execute query I get error:

```
ProgrammingError(1064, "1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON-LOOK'', ''ONLOOK KOREA'', ''master@on-look.co.kr'', ''Entertainment'', ''1.28' at line 1", u'42000'))
```

How to fix it?

Comment: In your `sql`, replace `%s` with placeholder `?`

Comment: replace all `%s` to `?`  ? or on `%?`

Comment: it works, but sometimes I get another error: `InterfaceError(-1, 'Use cmd_query_iter for statements with multiple queries.', None))`

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19783550/2343086) for InterfaceError above