# Exception hanling when using SQLALchemy session.execute for raw query with multiple statemens

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

While trying to update a non-existing column in a single statement throws an exception:

```
session.execute("UPDATE users SET wrong_column = test@test.com;")
```

If I do the same with multiple statements, the exception is not raised:

```
session.execute("UPDATE users SET email = test@test.com; UPDATE users SET wrong_column = test@test.com;")
```

One [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57541329/7269299) proposed is to split the query by the delimiter `;`:

But this does not work in my particular case as my query also consist of a few functions that have a delimiter in the `RETURN ... ;` statement and then again the `END;` statement, so the split would break the query.
(I know I could also try to split the query with `sqlparse` but installing an extra library for that also seems weird to me)

Is there really no better way to check if all statements in a raw query were executed without error?

I also tried to find something in the `CursorResult` object that is returned by the `session.execute` func, but I could not find anything.

(I'm working with a MySQL DB in case it matters)

Comment: I can't find any supportive docs, but my gut feel is that `execute` is designed for single statements. If you want to execute multiple text statements you might be better off using the DB-API cursor, as shown in some of the answers to the Q&A that you linked.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb

This worked totally fine:


```
    cursor = db_session.connection().connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
```